# Undefined index:

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

I get this error:
Notice: Undefined index: gender \form.php on line 26.please help..how solve this error..?

how get from form employee gender male or female and insert  MySQL database

```
**my html code**
```

```html
<form action="form.php" method="post">
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Form Input Employees Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <form method="post" action="form.php">
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td><input name="employe_name" type="text" id="employe_name" size="20">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Address</td>
          <td><input name="employe_add" type="text" id="employe_add" size="40">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="23">Gender</td>
    <td>Male<input type="radio" name="gender"value="m" />
    Female<input type="radio" name="gender"value="f"/>
    </td></tr>
    
    <td>
          <td align="right"><input type="submit" 
          name="submit" value="Submit"> add</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table></form>
```

And 
my PHP code is...

```
<?php

//Open a new connection to the MySQL server
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','employe');

//Output any connection error
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}else{
    echo"connection good";
}
if(isset($_POST['gender']))
{

    $gender=$_POST['gender'];
    echo("your are select" .$gender);


}
//get values from form
$employe_name=$_POST['employe_name'];
$employe_add=$_POST['employe_add'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];


//insert data into mysql



$sql = "INSERT INTO employe_detail(employe_name,employe_add,gender) VALUES('$employe_name','$employe_add','$gender')";

print '<h3>Insert a record</h3>';



if($sql)
{
    print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$mysqli->insert_id .'<br />'; 
}else{
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

please help me............

Comment: nested forms, and you're also not querying

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from

```
if(isset($_POST['gender']))
{

    $gender=$_POST['gender'];
    echo("your are select" .$gender);


}
//get values from form
$employe_name=$_POST['employe_name'];
$employe_add=$_POST['employe_add'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
```

To

```
$gender = "";
if(isset($_POST['gender']))
{

    $gender=$_POST['gender'];
    echo("your are select" .$gender);


}
//get values from form
$employe_name=$_POST['employe_name'];
$employe_add=$_POST['employe_add'];
```

gender will be assigned or will be left blank

Comment: that's but a band-aid.